# How to link to a Category inside of a Static Block using XML and Category ID

Tags: magento-1.7, catalog, cms

I know I can link to any category by using:

```
<a href="magento-store.com/category">Category</a>
```

But I was wondering if there was a way to do something like this:

```
<a href="{{url=category ID}}">Category</a>
```

I haven't been able to find anything like that. Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the category link widget. Let's say you want to add a link to category with ID 12. Add this to your cms page/block:

```
{{widget type="catalog/category_widget_link" anchor_text="Some text" title="Some text" template="catalog/category/widget/link/link_inline.phtml" id_path="category/12"}}
```

This will generate:

```
<a href="http://mysite.com/category/path.html" title="Some text">Some text</a>
```

If you don't add the parameters `andchor_text` and `title` the category name will be used.

Comment: Is there a way I can include HTML inside the category link widget?

Comment: What do you mean? Give me an example.

Comment: For example, if I wanted to create a hyperlink around an image like so.  <a href="http://mysite.com/category/path.html" title="Some text"><img src="imgsource.jpg" /></a>

Comment: The parameter anchor_text is the text inside the `<a>` tag. I'm not sure you can add `<img />` tags, but you can try.

Comment: `<img />` not working in `anchor_text` parameter. Isn't there any other way to link image to category?

Comment: A <span> is inserted in the <a>, so you can style it: `display: block` with `height` and `width`

Answer (score 0):

The linking structure in magento is a mess. CMS pages without closing braces and Categorry pages with. The answer here also omits to inform you that using the widgets prepends the URL with the store identifiers which add a whole new level of mess at the end of the URL which requires changes to the .htaccess file.

The manual way I would recommend however as stated in previous posts this may lead to broken links when url are updated or categories renamed.